# How to search inside installed add-ons in Firefox

Tags: firefox, firefox-extensions

On the ***about:addons*** page in Firefox there seems be no way of searching inside your own already installed add-ons. When I press <kbd>ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>f</kbd> it goes to the search box which obviously doesn't do that. Is there a workaround?

The funny thing is that searching inside my add-ons had existed before in Firefox 54. Why on earth they should remove a useful function like that in later updates?

[image: Firefox 54 search inside add-ons]

Comment: That functionality might simply not exist.

Comment: @Joseph but this functionality had existed before in FF 54. There should be some way to bring it back.